# Windows 2012 Shared Drives Odd Latency Issue

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, latency, mappeddrive

I have a Dell T110 II running ESXi 5.5 with a Windows 2012 R2 instance running with the following roles:

1. ADDS
2. DHCP
3. DNS
4. File/Storage Svcs
5. WSUS

I have two shared folders -- Scans and Data -- which are mapped via logon script:

```
net use B: \\Server\Data /persistent:yes
```

`net use I: \\Server\Scans /persistent:yes`

This configuration has been running without issue for slightly over a year until earlier this week when all workstations noticed a significant latency issue when browsing the mapped drives, particularly when navigating up to the parent directory from a subdirectory, loading (green bar in file explorer) takes anywhere between 10-20 seconds to appear. Users are also experiencing saving files to the mapped drives that later do not appear, as well as modifying data on the mapped drives, saving it and noticing their changes were never saved. Also, saving directly to mapped drives cause a "Not Responding" error in Word and Excel (2013), sometimes it recovers, sometimes it doesn't. Performance monitors on the workstations/server show no resource strain whatsoever in any category (barely 1% network usage, processors and RAM significantly low in usage as well).

I've replaced all network hardware with brand new hardware that has been tried true and tested and still the same problem occurs. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I missed anything I should have mentioned, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say based on the information provided, as a lot of things could cause "slowness."  However, you say that you've checked network, processor, and RAM, but you don't say that you've checked your disks/IO.

Check your disks and disk IO, especially things like whether your RAID array has a dead drive in it.

(This is a bit long for a comment.)